# Selecting table rows with jquery, but also selecting rows when clicking button, how do I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you click on a table row it adds a class that changes it's appearance to reflect it's selected.

```
    $('#my_table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } );
```

However, I also have some buttons in a column that let you do things specific to the row:

```
Item    Amount    Action
--------------------------------
Apple   10        [Buy] [Delete]
Banana  5         [Buy] [Delete]
Orange  14        [Buy] [Delete]
```

When I click one of the individual buttons, it also triggers the table row '.selected' class to be added, but I don't want this to occur when clicking buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Event​.stop​Propagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on button click:

```js
$('#my_table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
} );
$('#my_table tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.selected{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my_table">
  <thead>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td><button>[Buy]</button><button>[Delete]</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td><button>[Buy]</button><button>[Delete]</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td><button>[Buy]</button><button>[Delete]</button></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might make sure that the `td` being clicked on is not in the column with the buttons. With `:not`, you can ensure that the matched element doesn't match a particular selector, and with `:nth-child`, you can specify the 3rd `td` in its container as the one to be excluded:

```js
$('#my_table tbody').on('click', 'tr td:not(:nth-child(3))', function() {
  console.log('click registered');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my_table">
  <tr>
    <td>td 1</td>
    <td>td 2</td>
    <td><button>button</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answers are usually awesome but this teaches the OP nothing about the reasons why the refined querySelector solves his problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stopPropagation() or preventDefault() on buttons onclick event. This will prevent event bubling to parent elements of button (td, tr, table and so on). Assuming your buttons class as 'row-button' following is a sample code:

```
$('.row-button').on('click', function(event)){
    event.stopPropagation();
    //Do what are intended upon button click.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a feature of the DOM called [Event Propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation).

What you want to do is prevent this from occurring by calling [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in the handlers for your `<td>` clicks

To stop propagation with a jQuery event handler, simply return false on the last line of your td click handlers.